# Elucidat SCORM 2004 Upload to SAP Success Factors – Apparent XML Schema Issue

Tags: xml, scorm, scorm2004, sap-successfactors

I have SCORM 2004 skinny and full packages published out of Elucidat. These are test courses for a client using SAP Success Factors LMS, which I don't have access to.

These are the two errors my client is receiving:

1. Sample_SCORM2004_skinny_package - Error on line 8: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://www.client.org/course":lom}'. One of '{WC[##other:"www.client.org/course"]}' is expected.
2. Sample_SCORM2004_full_package - Error on line 22: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://www.client.org/course":controlMode}'. One of '{"http://www.client.org/course":randomizationControls, "http://www.client.org/course":deliveryControls, WC[##other:http://www.client.org/course]}' is expected.

I ran an XML validation on the manifest file for each of these, no errors. They also work when launching locally. This appears to be something unique to SAP SF, but I don't have access to their environment. I have a logged a ticket to see if they get to back to me.

Anyone here have any experience with SAP SF and XML issues?

Thank you

Comment: Try validating in SCORM Cloud... it should tell you if there are any manifest errors. If no errors, the issue is prob specific to SAP.